# Vusjs Vee-validate add class if no errors after validate

Tags: vue.js

Ik  have the following input.vue template, everything works fine, but how can i implement/add a class if after input some text and and validate has no errors?

```
<input 
    v-validate="validate" 
    v-on:input="updateValue($event)" 
    :type="type" 
    :placeholder="placeholder"
    :name="name" :value="value" 
    :class="{'form-control':'form-control','errorinput': errors.has(name)}" 
    :id="id">


export default {
    inject: ['$validator'],
    props: {
        validate: String,
        type: String,
        placeholder: String,
        name: String,
        value: String,
        classname: String,
        id: String,
        label: String,
        labelvalue: String
    },
    methods: {
        updateValue: function (evt) {
            console.log(this.errors);
            this.$emit('input', evt)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share a working jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after validate, the field would have a `dirty` flag. You can get a dirty flag by doing `$validator.fields.find({ name: name }).flags.dirty`.

This is an example of how you can add a class after validated while without error, by combining `dirty` and `errors.has`

```
 :class="{
    'form-control':'form-control',
    'errorinput': errors.has(name),
    'noerrorinput': $validator.fields.find({ name: name }) 
                    && $validator.fields.find({ name: name }).flags.dirty 
                    && !errors.has(name)
    }"
```

Comment: i changed this && !errors.has('email') into && !errors.has(name) and works great, thnx mate!